# I used a work VPN on my personal computer at home while doing..."non-work" things...am I in trouble/can they see me?

Tags: network, privacy, vpn

I was using my own home personal computer on a weekend while connected to my work's VPN (it's called pulse secure), and was bored so I decided to look at some "non-work" related websites (possibly/definitely nsfw stuff). Am I exposed? Can they see all my activity? Obviously I don't know anything about this stuff so please help me out cause I'm kinda panicking.

Edit: Added Route Table Below

```
===========================================================================
Interface List

13...02 05 85 7f eb 80 ......Juniper Networks Virtual Adapter

15...60 45 cb 81 cc d8 ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:

Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric

0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.158     25

0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0         On-link      10.2.100.225      1

10.2.100.225  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.2.100.225    256

127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

151.188.247.203  255.255.255.255      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.158     25

192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.1.158    281

192.168.1.158  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.158    281

192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.158    281

224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.1.158    281

224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      10.2.100.225    256

255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331

255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.1.158    281

255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      10.2.100.225    256

===========================================================================

Persistent Routes:

None
```

Edit:

Via company's IT handbook: "All user activity on any County information system and County-approved mobile communications or
fixed devices is subject to monitoring, logging, auditing, review, dissemination and archiving"

I'm pretty sure this quote answers my question.

Comment: There's no way to answer that question without knowing how the VPN is configured. If it tunnels all traffic (private and public) through it, yes they can see what you went to. If they don't (if it only routes private traffic through the tunnel but leaves internet traffic to route through your own provider), they could still see the DNS queries if they force you to use their DNS servers instead of your own or public servers.

Comment: If you can connect to the VPN and grab a copy of the route table it provides to you once connected, we can answer more accurately.

Comment: It does look like they advertise a default route to you.  If you want to test it out just to be sure, while NOT connected to the VPN, go to https://www.whatismyip.com and note your IP, then connect to the VPN and do the same test. If the IP matches, they are not routing internet traffic through the VPN; if it doesn't match, they are routing internet traffic through the VPN (in which case they COULD see you what you went to, but it would still depend on if they have logging enabled for that purpose or if they have some kind of proxy they route traffic through that might log traffic).

Comment: yeah the ip addresses are different...so that sucks

Comment: how do i check to see if logging is enable or if they have a proxy route they route traffic through?

Comment: It does but it still may not mean they saw what you did. Like I said, if they aren't logging internet traffic (which most companies don't do, because it could become a privacy issue or be too strenuous on a logging system due to the amount of traffic), you're possibly in the clear.  Generally if a company is logging internet traffic they also have it being filtered to prevent misuse.  Since it didn't stop you from going to NSFW sites, there's a good chance they aren't logging it.  You can always try asking if they log or look in the company policy handbook.

Comment: Short of asking, you'd have to be an admin of the VPN appliance to see what it's set to do.  Even if they did see what you went to, it can possibly be explained away by saying you didn't know that you were using their internet connection to browse rather than your own, and that it won't happen again now that you know how it's configured.

Comment: Yeah I checked the company handbook and they can log/track my activity...

Comment: I'd just not mention it unless they do, and make sure to never do it again.  Like I said, if they really want to bust people for browsing NSFW sites they'd probably have blocked it right off the bat using a content gateway like WebSense or Barracuda.

Comment: I see the policy excerpt and that's pretty generic. That likely just means that they CAN do all of that in the event that there's a reason to (like if someone catches you looking at malicious sites at work and reports you to IT security, they may initiate logging to see if it's true).  I don't think they are at all times otherwise it would probably say so (that all activities are logged at all times).

Comment: I'd just suggest being careful going forward.

Comment: The reason I realized I was still connected to my VPN is because I was downloading something and the file stopped downloading suddenly and so I just tried re-downloading it a couple of times, and then noticed I was still connected to the VPN. After I disconnected from the VPN the file downloaded fine. This makes me think my company may have been tracking me in some way. What do you think?

Comment: It's possible that they killed the traffic due to over- utilization of bandwidth and maybe hurting other people's speeds but I'm not sure I  would look too far into it being probable (that may just be me, though).

Comment: You meant to say "[wouldn't] look too far into it being probable" right?

Comment: No.  I just reread what I said and I was saying that "I'm not sure I would", and in I probably wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

I think they can.
Assuming that the 192.168.1.0 network is your home-network and the 10.2.100.0 network the VPN network, this line in your routing table:

```
Network Destination Netmask Gateway Interface Metric

0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 192.168.1.1 192.168.1.158 25

0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 On-link 10.2.100.225 1
```

Show that the VPN Gateway has a lower Metric value than your home gateway.
This means that all routing to any IP address (`0.0.0.0`) will first be TRIED over the VPN.

If the VPN is configured to block this, your normal route will be followed, but, technically, your company can LOG packets incoming on the VPN interface.

So to your question, "CAN they see what I'm doing", the answer is, yes, likely.

Comment: If they were "blocking" it, it wouldn't be advertised in the first place.  Also, in my opinion, this should not be listed as answer as nothing you said is conclusive and is all based upon assumption just as was discussed already in the above comments.

Comment: So this is not a possible answer based on the routing tables? Could you also elaborate on `it wouldn't be advertised in the first place` ?

Comment: When you define a client VPN, you essentially advertise which routes you want sent over the VPN. You can just route specific private networks/hosts over it, route ALL traffic through it (which is what we know this person's is doing), or route private and SOME public over it but not others).  The presence of the default route means that the VPN is configured to receive all traffic originating from the client. If they don't actually want all traffic from the client the VPN appliance would not be set to tunnel ALL traffic - it would be set to only tunnel specific/explicit routes.

Comment: I was talking about `iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -i tap0 --dport 80 -j LOGNDROP` kind of 'blocking'. Which wouldn't affect advertisement of routing tables as far as I know. Should've specified that.

Comment: I say it's not an answer (as opposed to speculation) because it doesn't actually answer anything about whether the company can see what the use did, conclusively. There is no way to know that from the info the user is able to gather.  Therefore, it should just be a comment, as far as I'm concerned.  If you want to keep it as an answer, that's your call. It was just a suggestion.

Comment: I know you CAN do it like you mentioned, but if you're doing that, it would be mostly useless to advertise the default route, unless the intent is to prevent the user from all browsing except to private sites. You can already set the VPN to tunnel all but then block it directly on the VPN appliance by means of a VPN-filter or similar.

Comment: I still feel my answer is pretty conclusive, you are free to flag it as not an answer for the mods to decide.

Comment: Like I said, it doesn't feel like an actual answer to me but I'm leaving it to you to decide.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to check is to go to whatismyip.com and find out your IP. Then connect to the VPN and try again. If you get the same IP, then they are using a "split tunnel" VPN which means only your traffic for the company network will go over it.

If you see a different IP, then it's likely they are doing "full tunnel" VPN and will have seen your traffic. You can do a WHOIS on the IP to confirm who it belongs to.

That said, if you are on your personal computer in your own time then they likely can't/won't do anything unless what you were looking at was actually illegal rather than just NSFW. Your security team might look at you funny though.